# Deploy iOS application from Greece

Tags: ios, deployment, app-store, appstore-approval

I understand that this might be an inappropriate question, but I really wanna make sure before I start being "involved" in the App Store.

So, lets say I have developed an application for iPhone with XCode adn want to deploy to the App Store. Also, lets say I want to charge the users for the app. In Google Play, google does not allow you to "earn money" through google play if you live in certain countries (Greece is one of them). Is this the same for the App Store either?

I know I must create a Developer's Account in the app store and that it costs 99$ anually. But in order to charge for the application, do I have to live in (lets say) Russia or USA, or can I do it even if I live in Greece?

Thank you for your patience and your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is this the same for the App Store either?*

No, you can earn money from the first app you sell (even if you sell one single copy).

*do I have to live in (lets say) Russia or USA, or can I do it even if I live in Greece?*

Doesn't matter where you live. You have the ability to specify in which **territories** you prefer to provide your app, and the sales reports are sent to you separated by territory.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! So basically I will have to enroll for the iOS programme, wait for the activation from apple, activate it and I can deploy my application to the app store. Right?

Comment: Yes right. The only think(problem) you might faced on submission process will be if there is a single mismatch between your name in your account and the name of bank account which you will pay for enrolment.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to create an Apple ID and selected Greece as country and everything went ok.

I've read in some forums problems a while ago (2010) regarding payment with credit card. The problems were solved by sending a wire transfer to Apple and a PDF with the application (however I think this is not necessary at the moment).

You can try to create a developer account (it's free) and if everything goes well you can then buy the license that you need.